# Multiple Monitor support for a VM-Ware hosted Machine?

Tags: remote-desktop, vmware-server

I want to virtualize several high-end users who have dual/multi-monitors. Is there a way to access a VM-Ware Server hosted machine and return it to a desktop with multiple screens so that it would better simulate the native machine?

Systems have CADD/GIS uses where tables and graphic views are needed at the same time for efficient use; but the stability of a VM/Central machine is critical for performance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk to your VMWare representative about VMware View to see if it's a good fit.  Also, if you go full screen while accessing said VMs it should have gone across both monitors.